# How to set functions for a property()?

Tags: python, oop, properties, getter-setter

This is a snippet for registers for an emulator I'm working on:

```
class registers(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._AF = registerpair()
    def _get_AF(self):
        return self._AF.getval()
    def _set_AF(self, val):
        self._AF.setval(val)
    AF = property(_get_AF, _set_AF)
```

The `registerpair()` class has an `increment()` method. I would like to know if there is any way I could do the following:

```
r = registers()
r.AF.increment()
```

rather than having to do:

```
r._AF.increment()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is, no. You have set the `fget` method to return a `getval()` for your `registerpair()` class.

Since the property is for the `_AF` attribute which is a `registerpair()` instance, I believe it would be more reasonable to change your `fget` (and `fset` for that matter) to actually return it, and maybe create an auxiliary function to actually get the value with `getval()` or access it directly.

So if your `_get_AF` looked something like:

```
def _get_AF(self):
    return self._AF
```

you can then call `r.AF.increment()` just fine. Then you could move the `getval()` call to another function in your class:

```
def getAFval(self):
    self._AF.getval()
```

Or just make direct calls like `r.AF.getval()` which seems like the most clear way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

You are effectively modifying the interface to the registerpair class using this wrapper class, and in doing so hiding the original interface. As such in your new interface the property() in Python refers to the values stored in the registerpair, not to the registerpair itself, as it reimplements the getval() and setval() interface of the registerpair.

So a couple of suggestions, firstly if this wrapper class is just reimplementing the interface to the registerpair, should you not just inherit from the registerpair, that way the original interface would be available?

Alternatively you could implement the remainder of the registerpair interface, using for example a method such as registers.increment_AF():

```
class registers(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self._AF = registerpair()
   def _get_AF(self):
       return self._AF.getval()
   def _set_AF(self, val):
       self._AF.setval(val)
   AF = property(_get_AF, _set_AF)

   def increment_AF(self):
       self._AF.increment()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly

You can call `r._AF.increment()` which references `registerpair()` object **but** since self._AF is a private method you cannot use

```
r.AF.increment()
```

for further information..check this

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

an extract from this site

```
_single_leading_underscore : weak "internal use" indicator. E.g. from M import * does not import objects whose name starts with an underscore.

single_trailing_underscore_ : used by convention to avoid conflicts with Python keyword, e.g.
```